# Can functional fields in OpenERP have inner function's execution precedence?

Tags: openerp-7

Assume I have two fields, and a functional field in, say, module1:

```
class my_class(osv.osv):
    _name = 'my.class'

    def _subtotal(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
        return {obj.id: obj.quantity * obj.price for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)}

    _columns = {
        'quantity': fields.float(string=_('Quantity')),
        'price': fields.float(string=_('Price')),
        'subtotal': fields.function(_subtotal, type='float', method=True, store=False, string=_('Subtotal'))
    }
```

And another field and another functional field in module2 (with dependency to module1):

```
class my_class(osv.osv):
    _name = 'my.class'
    _inherit = 'my.class'

    def _discounted(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
        return {obj.id: obj.subtotal - obj.discount for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)}

    _columns = {
        'discount': fields.float(... params ...)
        'discounted': fields.function(_discounted, type='float', method=True, store=False)
    }
```

Do I have any kind of guarantee that `_discounted` will be executed AFTER `_subtotal`? How does it vary if I use `store=True` in functional fields?

**Please**: Do not assume I can put both calculations in the same module (a constraint in the problem is that functions are in different modules, and no answer will be accepted if the provided solution is to join such calculations in the same module). This is just an example to illustrate my problem and doubts, and not the real-world code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, module2 is dependent on module1. So module1 will be installed first and then came inheritance. Since you have put **store="false"**, in this case you don't have to worry about which one will execute first.

Because even if your module2 **_discounted** method is triggered first means, it is going to call **obj.subtotal** which will trigger the **subtotal** function field by ORM. Due to **store="false"** property your module1 **_subtotal** gets executed and the result returned to your module2.

Don't go for **store="true"**. In that case, once value is stored in db you need to specify a triggering field to recompute the value or else all the fields in the object will act as triggering field.